# How can i create a "fake" dataset based on a real one?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, dataset, data-science

I am in the process of creating a "fake" dataset. Let me explain, I already have a dataset (of course I tried to study its topology as much as possible. That is with a study of correlation as well as the relations of variables to variables). My question is now that I "know the characteristics" of the dataset, how can I approach in the best possible way the creation of a dataset resembling as much as possible my original one while wanting to be able to integrate perturbations.

As i said, i only take a look at the data 'topology'. From here i am not convinced on what/how to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain a realistic "fake" dataset, you could try to train a generative model on your real data.

Assuming you are working with tabular data, there are architectures like CTGAN or TVAE that might be handy.

Some useful links regarding the topic:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-generate-tabular-data-using-ctgans-9386e45836a6

https://sdv.dev/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Faker library in Python - its really easy to set up and start using

https://towardsdatascience.com/free-resources-for-generating-realistic-fake-data-da63836be1a8